# How to sort associative array using sub-field of contained associative arrays in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, asort

How can I sort an associative array by one of its values?

For example:

```
$arr = array(
    'ted' => array( 'age' => 27 ),
    'bob' => array( 'age' => 18 ),
    'jay' => array( 'age' => 24 )
);

$arr = ???

foreach ($arr as $person)
    echo $person['age'], ', ';
```

So that the output is:

```
18, 24, 27
```

This is an oversimplified example just to demonstrate my question.

I still require that `$arr` is an associative array.

Comment: If you search the stack - you will find many answers http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+sort+associative+array

Comment: exactly the same question been asked within a hour

Comment: No offense @Lea Hayes but just thinking about why is possible here at SO to ask without basic knowledge about how this site is working.

Comment: sorting an associative array of associative arrays is *not* a duplicate

Comment: +1 @chriso for correctly identifying what was being asked here and flying in the face of the naysayers who would incorrectly mark it down as a duplicate question. If it weren't for your comment above I wouldn't have lingered here any longer and wouldn't have found the answer to my own very similar question. Thanks very much!

Comment: @DanSolo thank you for suggesting a more accurate title, I have tweaked your suggestion a little because I feel that it is important to emphasise that we are sorting by a sub-field. I was tempted to explicitly indicate that this was relevant to arrays of objects also except there are no suitable examples on this page. Writing a sort callback to achieve this is practically the same though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [**`uasort()`**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) function allows you to specify a callback function, which will be responsible of doing the comparison between two elements -- so, should do just well, if you implement the proper callback function.

Here, you'd have to implement a callback function that will receive two arrays -- and compmare the `age` item :

```
function callback($a, $b) {
  if ($a['age'] > $b['age']) {
    return 1;
  } else if ($a['age'] < $b['age']) {
    return -1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Using that function in the following portion of code :

```
$arr = array(
    'ted' => array( 'age' => 27 ),
    'bob' => array( 'age' => 18 ),
    'jay' => array( 'age' => 24 )
);

uasort($arr, 'callback');
var_dump($arr);
```

You would get you this resulting array :

```
array
  'bob' => 
    array
      'age' => int 18
  'jay' => 
    array
      'age' => int 24
  'ted' => 
    array
      'age' => int 27
```

Comment: Are you sure that your comparison function works correctly in all cases? According to the manual *The comparison function must return an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if the first argument is considered to be respectively less than, equal to, or greater than the second.* Your comparison function only returns `true` which will be casted to `1` or `false` which is `0` respectively.

Comment: @Stefan : ergh ; I should have re-read the maual page, and though a bit more ; I've edited my answer to fix that ; thanks for your comment !

Answer (score 7):

This is a classical example where PHP 5.3 anonymous functions come in handy:

```
uasort($arr, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['age'] - $b['age'];
});
```

The `$a['age'] - $b['age']` is a small *trick*. It works because the callback function is expected to return a value < 0 is `$a` is smaller than `$b` and a value > 0 if `$a` is bigger than `$b`.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

This particular case will involve using one of the sort methods that use a callback to sort

Answer (score 1):

Since you're sorting on a value inside a sub array, there's not a built-in function that will do 100% of the work.  I would do a user-defined sort with:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php

Here's an example comparison function that returns its comparison based on this value in the nested array

```
<?php
// Comparison function
function cmp($left, $right) {
    $age1 = $left['age'];
    $age2 = $right['age'];
    if ($age1 == $age2) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($age1 < $age2) ? -1 : 1;
}

uasort($array, 'cmp');
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not just sorting an associative array, you're sorting an associative array of associative arrays ;)

A [uasort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) call is what you're after

```
uasort($array, function ($a, $b) {
    if ($a['age'] === $b['age']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return $a['age'] > $a['age'] ? 1 : -1;
});
```