# php array to html table sort by columns

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have a php array that is output to a table.  But I need to sort the table by the first column, the second, third and fourth.  Im not sure if I should use a function or ksort.  What I have is below.  I also seem to have some Notice: Use of undefined constants when I run it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<?php
$state=array
(
array('Alabama', 'Montgomery', 4779736, 23),
array('Alaska', 'Juneau', 710231, 47),
array('Arizona', 'Phoenix', 6329017, 18),
array('Arkansas', 'LittleRock', 2915918, 32),
array('California', 'Sacramento', 37253956, 1),
array('Colorado', 'Denver', 5029196, 22),
array('Connecticut', 'Hartford', 3518288, 29),
array('Delaware', 'Dover', 897934, 45),
array('Florida', 'Tallahassee', 18801310, 4),
array('Georgia', 'Atlanta', 9687653, 9),
array('Hawaii', 'Boise', 1360301, 42)
);

echo "<table border=\"5\" cellpadding=\"10\">";
echo'<tr>';
   echo('<th>' . State. '</th>');
   echo('<th>' . Capital. '</th>');
   echo('<th>' . Population. '</th>');
   echo('<th>' . Rank. '</th>');
 echo'</tr>';

for ($i=0; $i<11; $i++)
{echo('<tr>');
  for ($j=0; $j<4; $j++)
  {echo ('<td>' . $state[$i][$j] . '</td>');
  }
  echo('</tr>');
}
echo "</table>"

?>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my other try at the sort:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
$states[] = array('state' => 'Georgia', 'capital' => 'Atlanta', 'rank' => 9);
$states[] = array('state' => 'Alaska', 'capital' => 'Juneau', 'rank' => 47);
$states[] = array('state' => 'Alabama', 'capital' => 'Montgomery', 'rank' => 23);
$states[] = array('state' => 'Hawaii', 'capital' => 'Boise', 'rank' => 42);

$capital = array();
foreach ($states as $key => $row)
{
    $capital[$key] = $row['capital'];
}
echo \array_multisort($capital, \SORT_DESC, $states);

?>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is what I have so far, but for some reason, the numbered columns (population and rank) arent sorting correctly in their tables:

```
<?php 
$states=array
(
array('state' =>  'Alabama', 'capital' => 'Montgomery', 'population' => 4779736, 'rank' =>  23),
array('state' => 'Alaska', 'capital' =>  'Juneau', 'population' => 710231, 'rank' =>  47),
array('state' => 'Arizona',  'capital' => 'Phoenix',  'population' =>6329017, 'rank' =>  18),
array('state' => 'Arkansas',  'capital' => 'LittleRock',  'population' =>2915918, 'rank' =>  32),
array('state' => 'California', 'capital' =>  'Sacramento', 'population' => 37253956, 'rank' =>  1),
array('state' => 'Colorado',  'capital' => 'Denver', 'population' => 5029196,  'rank' => 22),
array('state' => 'Connecticut', 'capital' =>  'Hartford', 'population' => 3518288, 'rank' =>  29),
array('state' => 'Delaware',  'capital' => 'Dover',  'population' =>897934, 'rank' =>  45),
array('state' => 'Florida',  'capital' => 'Tallahassee', 'population' => 18801310, 'rank' =>  4),
array('state' => 'Georgia', 'capital' =>  'Atlanta', 'population' => 9687653,  'rank' => 9),
array('state' => 'Hawaii',  'capital' => 'Boise', 'population' => 1360301, 'rank' =>  42)
);


//Create index rows
foreach ($states as $row) {
  foreach ($row as $key => $value){
    ${$key}[]  = $value; //Creates $volume, $edition, $name and $type arrays.
  }  
}
echo '<h2>Below is the initial table</h2>';
echo "<table border=\"5\" cellpadding=\"10\">";
echo'<tr>';
   echo('<th> State </th>');
   echo('<th> Capital </th>');
   echo('<th> Population </th>');
   echo('<th> Rank </th>');
 echo'</tr>';
  foreach($states as $k => $val){ 
    echo "<tr> <td>".$val['state']."</td>
    <td>".$val['capital']."</td>
    <td>".$val['population']."</td>
    <td>".$val['rank']."</td></tr>  ";
  }
echo "</table>";


echo '<h2>Below is the State (first column) sort table - Ascending</h2>';
echo "<table border=\"5\" cellpadding=\"10\">";
echo'<tr>';
   echo('<th> State </th>');
   echo('<th> Capital </th>');
   echo('<th> Population </th>');
   echo('<th> Rank </th>');
 echo'</tr>';
 \array_multisort($state, \SORT_ASC, $states);
 foreach($states as $k => $val){ 
    echo "<tr> <td>".$val['state']."</td>
    <td>".$val['capital']."</td>
    <td>".$val['population']."</td>
    <td>".$val['rank']."</td></tr>  ";
  }
echo "</table>";


echo '<h2>Below is the Capital (second column) sort table - Descending</h2>';
echo "<table border=\"5\" cellpadding=\"10\">";
echo'<tr>';
   echo('<th> State </th>');
   echo('<th> Capital </th>');
   echo('<th> Population </th>');
   echo('<th> Rank </th>');
 echo'</tr>';
 \array_multisort($capital, \SORT_DESC, $states);
 foreach($states as $k => $val){ 
    echo "<tr> <td>".$val['state']."</td>
    <td>".$val['capital']."</td>
    <td>".$val['population']."</td>
    <td>".$val['rank']."</td></tr>  ";
  }
echo "</table>";


echo '<h2>Below is the Population (third column) sort table - Ascending</h2>';
echo "<table border=\"5\" cellpadding=\"10\">";
echo'<tr>';
   echo('<th> State </th>');
   echo('<th> Capital </th>');
   echo('<th> Population </th>');
   echo('<th> Rank </th>');
 echo'</tr>';
 \array_multisort($population, \SORT_ASC, $states);
 foreach($states as $k => $val){ 
    echo "<tr> <td>".$val['state']."</td>
    <td>".$val['capital']."</td>
    <td>".$val['population']."</td>
    <td>".$val['rank']."</td></tr>  ";
  }
echo "</table>";


echo '<h2>Below is the Rank (fourth column) sort table - Descending</h2>';
echo "<table border=\"5\" cellpadding=\"10\">";
echo'<tr>';
   echo('<th> State </th>');
   echo('<th> Capital </th>');
   echo('<th> Population </th>');
   echo('<th> Rank </th>');
 echo'</tr>';
 \array_multisort($rank, \SORT_DESC, $states);
 foreach($states as $k => $val){ 
    echo "<tr> <td>".$val['state']."</td>
    <td>".$val['capital']."</td>
    <td>".$val['population']."</td>
    <td>".$val['rank']."</td></tr>  ";
  }
echo "</table>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It might even be OP's PHP version. Mine is 5.4.23 @Jack

Comment: check[this link [How to sort associative array using sub-field of contained associative arrays in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498718/how-to-sort-associative-array-using-sub-field-of-contained-associative-arrays-in)

Comment: Can I sort by each column with the original array - without using a key?  Or should I use the second array syntax?  And how do I echo the sorted table?

Comment: If you are grabbing this array values from database, it would be really good to bring sorted results based on query as per required, that way you can sort each column ASC/DESC as required

Comment: This is not from a database.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Well, that clears it up; let's remove our comment thread then :)

Comment: Comments deleted @Jack

Comment: How exactly do you want your table sorted? @TheOneNOnlyQ

Comment: I need to output it 4 ways.  one by state, then capital, population and rank.  So Ill have 4 tables output on the screen.

Answer (score 4):

Use this code , i think  this is what you want ..

```
<?php 
$states=array
(
array('state' =>  'Alabama', 'capital' => 'Montgomery', 'population' => 4779736, 'rank' =>  23),
array('state' => 'Alaska', 'capital' =>  'Juneau', 'population' => 710231, 'rank' =>  47),
array('state' => 'Arizona',  'capital' => 'Phoenix',  'population' =>6329017, 'rank' =>  18),
array('state' => 'Arkansas',  'capital' => 'LittleRock',  'population' =>2915918, 'rank' =>  32),
array('state' => 'California', 'capital' =>  'Sacramento', 'population' => 37253956, 'rank' =>  1),
array('state' => 'Colorado',  'capital' => 'Denver', 'population' => 5029196,  'rank' => 22),
array('state' => 'Connecticut', 'capital' =>  'Hartford', 'population' => 3518288, 'rank' =>  29),
array('state' => 'Delaware',  'capital' => 'Dover',  'population' =>897934, 'rank' =>  45),
array('state' => 'Florida',  'capital' => 'Tallahassee', 'population' => 18801310, 'rank' =>  4),
array('state' => 'Georgia', 'capital' =>  'Atlanta', 'population' => 9687653,  'rank' => 9),
array('state' => 'Hawaii',  'capital' => 'Boise', 'population' => 1360301, 'rank' =>  42)
);


//Create index rows
foreach ($states as $row) {
  foreach ($row as $key => $value){
    ${$key}[]  = $value; //Creates $volume, $edition, $name and $type arrays.
  }  
}
array_multisort($state, SORT_ASC, $capital, SORT_ASC, $population, SORT_ASC, $rank , SORT_ASC,  $states);

echo "<table border=\"5\" cellpadding=\"10\">";
echo'<tr>';
   echo('<th> State </th>');
   echo('<th> Capital </th>');
   echo('<th> Population </th>');
   echo('<th> Rank </th>');
 echo'</tr>';

 foreach($states as $k => $val){ 

    echo "<tr> <td>".$val['state']."</td>
    <td>".$val['capital']."</td>
    <td>".$val['population']."</td>
    <td>".$val['rank']."</td></tr>  ";

  }

echo "</table>"

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you.  That got rid of the warning messages.  But I still am not sure on how to sort.  Does this array syntax make it harder to sort each column?

Comment: TheoneNOnlyQ , i have updated my answer above check it

Comment: Yes, thank you.  Thats one sort.  But I need to sort by the other 3 columns also.

Comment: OK   I see this will sort by capital   \array_multisort($capital, \SORT_ASC, $states);  But i need a loop Im guessing, to get the others  without retyping it all over again???